# how to fix ghostscript

Tags: python, path

I have already installed ghostscript with pip install ghostscript.
But I got the error with treepoemerror: Cannot determine path to ghostscript, is it installed?
I've changed gs to gswin64, because I've winx64:

```
def _get_ghostscript_binary() -> str:
    binary = "gswin64"

    if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
        binary = EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary
        if not binary:
            raise TreepoemError(
                "Cannot determine path to ghostscript, is it installed?"
            )

    return binary
```

but I still get that error. How do I set something with Path?
Can anyone give me the steps, easily explained?
So here's it installed:

[image: installed ghostscript]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Ghostscript problem, nor does Ghostscript appear to need fixed! First things first; have you actually installed Ghostscript ? I do not believe that 'pip install Ghostscript' actually installs Ghostscript, just the Python bindings. So check in /Program Files (or /Program Files (x86)) for the existence of a gs folder. If that's not there you have not installed Ghostscript. If it is then the Registry should have all that is required. You may, however, need to set the $PATH environment variable. Exactly how you do that depends on your version of Windows, best Google it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `pip install ghostscript` can install Python module which is only wrapper on program  `ghostscript` created with C/C++ - and you have to manually download and  install this `ghostscript` created with C/C++ and in Python set path to this `ghostscript` created with C/C++. See page https://www.ghostscript.com/